# Change keyboard type of a text field in Swift during runtime

Tags: swift, keyboard, textfield

I was wondering if there is a way to check if a text field contains a certain character and if that is the case, change the keyboard type displayed. This is what I have tried but it does not manage to change. This is action occurs when editing the text field is changed.

```
    @IBAction func decOrNot(_ sender: Any) {
    let cont = "1"
    let field = testKaede.text
    if (field!.contains(cont)) {
        self.testKaede.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
    }
    else {
        self.testKaede.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just call `reloadInputViews()` on your `UITextField` after you change keyboard's type

---

```
textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
textField.reloadInputViews()
```